# Python, API testing: assertion failed, but Actual and Expected seems to be same

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, pycharm

Im trying to run simple negative api test in Pycharm.
It compares json response of api call with "expected" data.
Call returns this:

```
{'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'}
```

And in our test we asserting actual response with ^ data.
 Test:

```
def test(environment):
resp = getSomeData(environment, negative)
respString = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
jsonResponse = json.loads(respString)
assert jsonResponse == "{'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'}"
```

When running this test with pytest in pycharm, it returns

```
{'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'} != {'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'}

    Expected :{'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'}
    Actual   :{'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'}
```

Please point me in right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are comparing `dict` with `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, your test should compare `jsonResponse` (which is a `dict`) with another `dict`, and not a string:

```py
assert jsonResponse == {'error_message': 'invalid UUID format'}
```

The test output is not very friendly in this case, as it makes you think that both objects are identical.